# Change multiindex to single using python

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have multiindex columns and need to change it single index:

```
df.columns:

Multiindex([('Name', ''),
          ( 'Type Product',  ''),
          (' revenue',   2021-10),
          ( 'revenue',   2021-11),
       names=[None,'month'])
```

Comment: you want to change it how?

Comment: need to change to single-index

Comment: Yes, I have name , type of product and revenue based on month, and need to change the columns from multi index to single index

Comment: it's still unclear, but you have two main options, flatten it (you need to define how), or drop a level (use `reset_index`)

Comment: can you write the code>

Comment: no because I do not know what you expect exactly